# Plus quantifier not working as expected using regex for substitution in sed

Tags: regex, sed

The input is **#PermitRootLogin no**. Why doesn't the following sed expression work with sed?

```
echo "#PermitRootLogin no" | sed 's/^#PermitRootLogin\s+.*/PermitRootLogin yes/'
```

but after I remove the + after the keyword it works?

```
echo "#PermitRootLogin no" | sed 's/^#PermitRootLogin\s.*/PermitRootLogin yes/'
```

I thought the **+** after a **\s** would mean one or more of the previous token.

[sed gist](https://sed.js.org/?gist=8608fa7ff97ee150ab49b782ecb38bd4)

PS: Works either way with regex101.com

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to escape the `+` sign:

In GNU sed, with basic regular expression syntax these characters `?`, `+`, parentheses, braces `({})`, and `|`  do not have special meaning unless prefixed with a backslash `\`.

The plus sign `+` in your case means match a literal `+`, so it would match the plus in `#PermitRootLogin +no`. You have to escape it in `\s\+` to be able to match one or more whitespace character `#PermitRootLogin        no`

```
echo "#PermitRootLogin no" | sed 's/^#PermitRootLogin\s\+.*/PermitRootLogin yes/'
```

Output:

```
PermitRootLogin yes
```

Comment: Cool.  But why? Don't need escape if I use *

Comment: @user603749 see [Why does my regular expression work in X but not in Y?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/119905/109046)

Comment: @user603749 with basic regular expression syntax the `*` has special meaning while the `+` not, unless prefixed with a backslash.